# PDF is not well formatted on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, html-pdf

I am generating the PDF from HTML. The run-time is node.js 10. The PDF is all-okay when the function is run in the firebase emulator. But the exact same code fails to produce a nicely formatted PDF. The part of CSS doesn't come into the effect.

How can I generate the well formatted PDF with google cloud functions running on Firebase/GCP ?

Below is the code snippet :

```
var htmlPdf = require('html-pdf');
........
........
async function generatePdf(htmlText,fileNumber) {

    var options = { 
        format: 'Letter',
        directory: "", 
        timeout: 540000,  // in milliseconds
        border: {
                    top: "1in",            // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
                    //right: "0.2in",
                    bottom: "1in",
                    left: "1in"
                  }
    };
    const fileName = `/tmp/payment-receipt-${fileNumber}.pdf`;
    
    htmlPdf.create(htmlText,options).toFile(fileName ,async (err, res)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error EC-002 ',err);
            return 'NOK';
        }

        console.log('file created as : ',res.filename);
     });
....
....
}
```

I already tried removing CSS external link and adding the relevant CSS classes in the  section of the HTML. It didn't work. There doesn't seem to be any problem with the external links since the HTML has one image (sourced from the internet) and it works well.
There's absolutely no problem when the code is run on a firebase emulator.

Comment: Where did you get the `htmlText` variable content?

Comment: It's the static HTML template. I just replace some values from the DB.

Comment: Is it valid? Did you try to log it to validate its content?

Comment: Yes. On the exact same data, the PDF is created correctly when ran on the local machine (with firebase emulator).